# github, use same private and public key cross different machines. permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh, private-key

Currently, I put all my private and public keys in bitbucket, then I clone them into different machines. e.g. home laptop, work desktop, etc.

Right now, I am using serria in Mac. I tested the private key with github and it seems fine.

```
ssh -i id_rsa_kenpeter -vT git@github.com


debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
Hi kenpeter! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2664, received 1776 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4164.9, received 2776.6
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I tried to push something to github and I got this.

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts:62
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.30.255.112
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fab0bd00f40)
debug2: key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/kenpeter/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It seems it didn't know how to use the private key `id_rsa_kenpeter`
I have lots of public/private key and a config file in .ssh. Bitbucket is working fine. How do I resolve for github?

Comment: Does your SSH config refer to that key?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656916/ansible-with-github-permission-denied-publickey).

Basically, I need to do `ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_private_key`

After adding the private key to ssh agent, it seems like setting a global variable then ssh is aware the private key and uses it. Ubuntu never need to add to ssh-add

Comment: You shouldn't need an SSH agent here, unless you're performing chained SSH operations.

Comment: Well, it is not working. I don't think I do any chained ssh operations.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems it didn't know how to use the private key `id_rsa_kenpeter`.

no, it does not know if you will not tell it how to use it, since it does not have standard name.

> I have lots of public/private key and a config file in .ssh. Bitbucket is working fine. How do I resolve for github?

Yes, your `~/.ssh/config` is a key to this question. Same way as you specified your key to the `ssh` command, you can do it in the configuration:

```
Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile id_rsa_kenpeter
```

You will also probably have to use a full path to that file, since you plan to use a git from different directories than the one where is the key file.